# fast selection of rows where at least N many columns hold true in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

If I have this `numpy` array:

```
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  6],
       [ 4, 10,  9]])
```

What's the fastest way to select out of it all the rows where a condition holds true of at least `N` many elements?

For example select all the rows where at least two numbers are evenly divisible by 2.

The solution I came up with is:

```
@ find rows where 2 or more elements are evenly divisible by two
N = 2  
a[where(array(map(lambda x: sum(x), a % 2 == 0)) >= N)]
```

An alternative solution using `apply_along_axis` is:

```
a[where(sum(numpy.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, 1, a), axis=1) >= 2)]
```

Is there a more elegant/faster way in numpy/scipy than these? If not, which of the above two is best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably do

```
In [29]: timeit a[(a % 2 == 0).sum(axis=1) >= 2]
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.5 us per loop
```

which works because True/False have integer values of 1/0.  For comparison:

```
In [30]: timeit a[where(array(map(lambda x: sum(x), a % 2 == 0)) >= N)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 72 us per loop

In [31]: timeit a[where(sum(apply_along_axis(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, 1, a), axis=1) >= 2)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 220 us per loop
```

Note that using lambdas costs you a lot of the benefits of using numpy in the first place, and `lambda x: sum(x)` is simply a more verbose and slower way of writing `sum` here anyway.

Also note that if the array were large, it'd probably be more efficient to use a method which could short-circuit rather than the above.

Comment: I have the same problem and the matrix is large. What method can do short circuit?